# Recent entry still showing on Files sidebar even with History disabled. Bug?

Tags: pantheon-files, bugs

I think this is a bug, or at least, UI inconsistency.

My privacy mode is on, meaning that history is disabled. If so, why does "Recent" still showing on Files sidebar? There's no purpose for it any more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue has been raised here: https://github.com/elementary/files/issues/1167.  Pressing the Recent bookmark with history off displays an informative message with a link to the Privacy settings so it is not entirely useless.

Comment: Noted. That was the right thing to do.